# What does this “how” do here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

I can’t get the meaning of “how” in an article. This is from the article column from The Guardian, **“Now we know there’s racial bias. The challenge is how to address it”**
https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/dec/07/racial-bias-address-prejudice

Please have a look at the embolden part.

> Imagine a life inside an open-topped glass box. You could see what was
>   around you, what your friends and neighbours and colleagues were
>   doing. You could probably hear what was happening. In many and varied
>   ways, you would be connected to your surroundings and have
>   expectations to match. But just reach out to touch something, to
>   connect, to truly become part of the life you see, and the fact of the
>   box asserts itself. You can’t. You are close to what’s outside – the
>   glass may be quite thin – but what separates you, as opaque as it may
>   be, determines your life.
>
> Think of that scenario, and you might get close to some of what we
>   have learned from a week of reporting in the Guardian’s Bias in
>   Britain project. **How** life in that glass box means that for all the
>   jobs certain people might see and reasonably aspire to, they never
>   quite seem able to match their aspiration. **How**, for all the
>   property ads that hold out the promise of a place to buy or rent,
>   people in the box fail, in ways and by margins that seem inexplicable,
>   to land the home they thought they could get. Why their friends,
>   unencumbered by invisible impediment, have a different experience when
>   they walk the high street, or go shopping, or go clubbing. Life is not
>   always awful, but it always falls short. It’s like chasing a £5 note
>   in the breeze. It forever seems reachable but, by fingertips’ length,
>   it isn’t. For so long now we have been told that the so-called scourge
>   of political correctness has irreparably tipped the scales towards
>   minorities. If this project does nothing else, it exposes that lie.

I can get the “how” and that makes it difficult for me to understand the two sentences that begin with “How.”
I need your help, thank you.

Comment: You may be thinking there is a one-to-one relation between "how" and a word in your native language.  However, there are very many different definitions of "how" : 
 https://www.dictionary.com/browse/how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is just before the first sentence that starts with ***how***.

> ...you might get close to some of **what we have learned** from a week of reporting...

The sentences are "what we have learned", so you can take an implicit "we have learned" before each of those sentences starting *how*.

> We have learned how life in that glass box means that for all the jobs certain people might see...
>
> We have learned how, for all the property ads that hold out the promise of a place to buy or rent...

The next one, as well:

> We have learned why their friends, unencumbered by invisible impediment, have a different experience...